# recycler not show any data until open keyboard device

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have recyclerview and get information from webservice.

```
public void Load() {
    counter = 0;
    adapterComment = new AdapterComment(G.context, comments);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterComment);

    VolleyRequestHelper volleyRequestHelper = new VolleyRequestHelper(Request.Method.POST, G.URL_ADDRESS_MUSIC + "get_song_comment/page/" + counter, map, new Response.Listener<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
      //get data
          }
          adapterComment.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      }
    });
Volley.newRequestQueue(G.context).add(volleyRequestHelper);
```

}
and i use the endless scroll every time recycler show 20 item , if data bigger not problem if data smaller 20 recycler not show data until open keyboard device (i have edittext in layer) .

```
public void LoadMore() {
    counter = (counter + 1);
    adapterComment = new AdapterComment(G.context, comments);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterComment);
    VolleyRequestHelper volleyRequestHelper = new VolleyRequestHelper(Request.Method.POST, G.URL_ADDRESS_MUSIC + "get_song_comment/page/" + counter, map, new Response.Listener<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
       //get data
          }
          adapterComment.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

      }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(G.context).add(volleyRequestHelper);
  }
```

and in onCreatView :

```
Load();
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
      @Override
      public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
        int lastFirstVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(lastFirstVisiblePosition);
        LoadMore();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Have you set layout manager to the recyclerview?

Comment: yes , i said in state item bigger 20 number no problem. just in state data smaller 20 item have problem because method load() and loadmore() run with him.